# Prompt Infinite Dialogs in MS Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using the Bot Framework on Node.js. I want to pull an undetermined number of questions from a file, and then prompt the user for answers for all of the questions. Is there any way to loop one dialog to accomplish this, or are there any other solutions that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the logic below you should be able to loop through every prompt in your file.

```
bot.dialog('prompting', [
    (session, args) => {
        if ('currentPrompt' in args) {
            let promptsData = promptRetriever();
            session.conversationData.currentPrompt = args.currentPrompt;

            // switch statement so the correct type of prompt is sent to the user
            switch (args.promptType) {
                case 'text':
                    builder.Prompts.text(session, promptsData[args.currentPrompt].text);
                    break;
                case 'confirm':
                    builder.Prompts.confirm(session, promptsData[args.currentPrompt].text);
                    break;
                case 'number':
                    builder.Prompts.number(session, promptsData[args.currentPrompt].text);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            let firstPrompt = promptRetriever()['prompt1'];
            session.conversationData.currentPrompt = 'prompt1';
            builder.Prompts.confirm(session, firstPrompt.text);
        }
    },
    (session, results) => {
        // Store the response for the value of the prompt on session.userData
        session.userData[session.conversationData.currentPrompt] = results.response;
        delete session.conversationData.currentPrompt;


        // Retrieve all the keys (prompts) from prompts.json
        let prompts = promptRetriever();

        // If the lengths are the same then every prompt has been asked, 
        // so respond with the user's answers.

        if (Object.keys(session.userData).length === Object.keys(prompts).length) {
            session.send('You answered all the prompts!')
                .send(`prompt1 result: ${session.userData.prompt1}`)
                .send(`prompt2 result: ${session.userData.prompt2}`)
                .send(`prompt3 result: ${session.userData.prompt3}`)
            session.endDialog('Ending dialog.');
        } else {
            let promptsKeys = Object.keys(prompts);
            for (let key in promptsKeys) {
                if (!(promptsKeys[key] in session.userData)) {
                    session.replaceDialog('prompting', {
                        currentPrompt: promptsKeys[key],
                        promptType: prompts[promptsKeys[key]].type }
                    );
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
]).triggerAction({
    matches: /prompts/ig
});

// Helper function for accessing out prompts in json format

function promptRetriever() {
    return require('./prompts.json');
}
```

---

And then the structure of prompts.json used for this example was:

```
{
    "prompt1": {
        "text": "Please say yes or no",
        "type": "confirm"
    },
    "prompt2": {
        "text": "Please say something",
        "type": "text"
    },
    "prompt3": {
        "text": "What is your age",
        "type": "number"
    }
}
```